# Adding a ranking column to a dataframe

Tags: r, ranking

This seems like it must be a very common task, but I can't find a solution in google or SO. I want to add a column called 'rank' to 'dat1' based on the sequence that 'order.scores' applies to 'dat'. I tried using row.names(), but the rownames are based on 'dat', not 'dat1'. I also tried 'dat$rank <-rank(dat1)', but this produces an error message.

```
fname<-c("Joe", "Bob", "Bill", "Tom", "Sue","Sam","Jane","Ruby")
score<-c(500, 490, 500, 750, 550, 500, 210, 320)
dat<-data.frame(fname,score)
order.scores<-order(dat$score,dat$fname)
dat1<-dat[order.scores,]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `dat$rank <- rank(dat$score)`?

Comment: Not exactly. My primary sort is dat$score, but my secondary (tie-breaker) sort is fname. So Bill ranks ahead of Joe, who in turn ranks ahead of Sam, even though they all have the same score. This is the sort order you see when you view 'dat1'. If I try 'dat1$rank <- rank(dat1$score)', Bill, Joe and Same all get rank 5.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can compute a ranking from an ordering as follows:

```
dat$rank <- NA
dat$rank[order.scores] <- 1:nrow(dat)
dat
#   fname score rank
# 1   Joe   500    5
# 2   Bob   490    3
# 3  Bill   500    4
# 4   Tom   750    8
# 5   Sue   550    7
# 6   Sam   500    6
# 7  Jane   210    1
# 8  Ruby   320    2
```

Comment: Nice. I also didn't realize that I had to create an empty rank column before I could assign values to it. Thanks very much.

Comment: Fixed it with `dat$rank[order(-dat$scores)] <- 1:nrow(dat)`. If this is a typo, please edit for the next one. :)

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger I used `order.scores` as defined in the original post, so you need to run the code from there in order for my code to work.

Comment: Right, my mistake. I did not know about the dot notation to create columns.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
## dat, dat1, and order.scores as defined
dat <- data.frame(fname=c("Joe", "Bob", "Bill", "Tom", "Sue","Sam","Jane","Ruby"),
                  score=c(500, 490, 500, 750, 550, 500, 210, 320))
order.scores <- order(dat$score)
dat1 <- dat[order.scores,]
dat1$rank <- rank(dat1$score)
dat1
##    fname score rank
##  7  Jane   210    1
##  8  Ruby   320    2
##  2   Bob   490    3
##  3  Bill   500    5
##  1   Joe   500    5
##  6   Sam   500    5
##  5   Sue   550    7
##  4   Tom   750    8
```

This shows the ties in rank based on `$score`. If you don't want ties in `$rank`, then you might as well say `dat1$rank <- 1:nrow(dat1)` since they are already in order.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use arrange and mutate from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- arrange(dat, desc(score)) %>%
          mutate(rank = 1:nrow(dat))
dat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
dat$Rank <-  rank(dat$score)
dat$Rank
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Comment: This doesn't address the original requirement that the primary sort be on "score" and the secondary sort be on "fname". The "rank" field should correspond to a position resulting from a 2-level sort. There should be no ties.

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
 dat$rank <- order(order.scores)
  dat$rank
 #[1] 5 3 4 8 7 6 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For the given dataframe `dat`:

```
  fname score
  Joe   500
  Bob   490
  Bill  500
  Tom   750
  Sue   550
  Sam   500
  Jane  210
  Ruby  320
```

We can also use `dplyr` as below, it assigns the `lowest` rank to the `smallest` value, which is `210` in this case.

```
ranks = dat %>%
  mutate(ranks = order(order(score)))
```

The output will be as below:

```
fname score ranks
  Joe   500     4
  Bob   490     3
 Bill   500     5
  Tom   750     8
  Sue   550     7
  Sam   500     6
 Jane   210     1
 Ruby   320     2
```

If the converse is required, i.e., rank `1` should be assigned to the `highest` value which is `750` in this case, then the code will be changed slightly as below:

```
ranks = dat %>%
  mutate(ranks = order(order(score, decreasing = T)))
```

The output in this case will be as below:

```
fname score ranks
Joe   500     3
Bob   490     6
Bill  500     4
Tom   750     1
Sue   550     2
Sam   500     5
Jane  210     8
Ruby  320     7
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally, Rank can be applied to find the least to highest in numerical values of a column data.

example: Salary is a column and it has 4 digit salary to 5 digit salary then here it goes by applying rank function!

simple understanding - the rank of salaries among them.

```
df['Salary'].rank(ascending = False).astype(int)
```

Comment: The question is in R, but you've answered with Python