# how to add ordering number to a data frame based on descending values of a column in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, tab-ordering

I have a toy data as follows:

```
toy.df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(10))
```

I want to add a new column indicating the order of values(descending) in col1. I need the order index to be numbers from 1:10.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `rank(-1 * toy.df$col1)`

Comment: Thanks, this gives me the order of values in data frame.  I need to stick this info to the table. How can I do that?

Comment: `toy.df$ord <- rank(-1 * toy.df$col1)`

Comment: in my real data, I get decimal number like "167.5" as order? How can I fix this?

Comment: You have ties in the data. Please explore how `rank` works through its documentation using `?rank` or `help(rank)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a ranking column to a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938172/adding-a-ranking-column-to-a-dataframe)

Comment: Actually, No. I am using dplyr to arrange the data and add the row numbers as the order: toy.df %>% arrange(col1) %>% distinct() %>% mutate(rank = row_number()). Thanks a lot. However for the toy data your answer is working.

Comment: If part of the problem is dealing with ties, that should be present in your example data. And if you need help incorporating this into your code, your relevant code should be in the question as well. Otherwise answers here won't be able to address your actual problem.